# Copy unicode data from MSSql to MySql in Python error

Tags: python-2.7, mysql-python, pymssql

I am trying to copy unicode data from MSSql to MySql. Below is the code that I am trying for past few days, but unable to do it successfully.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import MySQLdb
import pymssql

################
#connection variables go here
#################

conms = pymssql.connect(host=MSdbAddress, user=MSsuser, password=MSpass, database=MSdbName,  charset='UTF-8')  
curms = conms.cursor()

conmy = MySQLdb.connect(host=MYdbAddress, user=MYsuser, passwd=MYpass, db=MYdbName, charset='utf8')
curmy = conmy.cursor()

curms.execute("select top 1 * from " + MSdbTableName )
ms_list = curms.fetchall()
ms_list_1
for row in ms_list:
    for x in row:
        if isinstance(x,int):
            ms_list_1.append(x)
        elif isinstance(x,unicode):
            ms_list_1.append(x.encode('utf8'))
        else:
            ms_list_1.append(str(x))

curmy.execute("""insert into `MSdbTableName`  values (%s, %s, %s)""",  (ms_list_1[0], ms_list_1[1], ms_list_1[2])
```

When I try to insert unicode text without using ms_list, it works file
i.e.

```
curmy.execute("""insert into `MSdbTableName` (Content) values (%s)""", ('शांति से क्रोध को जीतें। मृदुता से अभिमान को जीतें। सरलता से माया को जीतें। संतोष से लोभ को जीतें।'))
```

Also when I check contents of ms_list, it decodes unicode correctly.
i.e.

> print str(ms_list_1[0]) + str(ms_list_1[1]) + str(ms_list_1[2])

But I am unable to insert it in MySql. I tried a few solutions on web but I am still stuck with 2 errors

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position
>   0: ordinal not in range(128)
>
> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

What am I missing something ?

Comment: You can try without encoding using utf-8. Probably pymssql return byte string, not unicode.

Comment: Could you use: ` curmy.execute(u"""insert into `MSdbTableName`  values (%s, %s, %s), ...""" ` ?